# In PhpStorm, what do I need a "HTTP connection" for?

Tags: ftp, phpstorm

I want to create a project with remote files via **FTP** connection. In the "Add remote server" dialog, I set up an FTP connection. "Test connection" told me it's valid, and I can choose root directory, so the FTP is working.

However, right under it, there is also a "Web server root URL" input and a "Don't check HTTP connection to server" checkbox. What do I need these for? What's the point of an HTTP connection, when I am using FTP? [Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/create-new-project-add-remote-server.html) doesn't explain this in no sense.

I even had to check the latter box, otherwise I couldn't continue to the import/synchronizing: it then says "Connection failed: Connection refused", *although* my FTP connection was stable. This initially actually made me think that I needed FTP *and* HTTP.

For visualisation purposes:

[image]

Comment: The screenshot you are showing is not from "Create new project" wizard but actual Deployment entry details which has no such check boxes.

Comment: @LazyOne yes thanks, fixed that

Comment: But to answer your question: URL from deployment entry is used when you choose to use `Open in Browser` or just `Debug this` kind of actions. If you do not have deployment entry at all (e.g. when you use `Open` and point to existing directory or create brand new empty project) then PhpStorm's own built-in simple web server will be used (which is fine for simple and average cases). In any case -- that option in "Create new project" wizard just checks if server is already available at that http address.

Comment: If you do not have web site running yet then you definitely need to check this option. If you have web site already available -- then use correct domain name (it just copies your FTP host name by default .. and your web server is unlikely to be configured to serve your site via `ftp.` in domain name. Sometimes the check may fail (AFAIK IDE sends `HEAD` requests .. and some web server configs may only allow POST & GET only .. or your site may have other restrictions/specific in place so HEAD may fail with 4xx response (most often it would be 403)) and wizard will be unable to proceed further.